# What do the Trapezoid-shaped boxes mean in this schematic diagram of RISC architectures (from Wirth's compiler construction)

Tags: architecture, hardware, diagrams

I am currently browsing through Niklas Wirth's compiler construction book. He presents a simple RISC architecture as a target for code generation using the following diagram. The symbols/shapes used are not explained in detail, though. Registers/storage seems to be presented with bold-borders. I wonder what the trapezoid boxes indicate and why their shape is different from other rectangular kins.

For example, ALU is trapezoid, incremented is rectangular. (I know ALU is an arithmetic logical unit, this question is about why the trapezoid form).

[image]

My current hypothesis is that the shape just indicates that one trapezoid unit processes multiple inputs to one output. Is that the correct view?

Comment: Probably: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer

Comment: @Mat could be an interesting starting point but is the ALU (arithmetic logic unit) a multiplexer?

Comment: No but it has the same "shape" (two inputs one output). Selection logic is missing in the diagram for the mux, but for "high-level" diagram seems to fit.

Comment: The ALU is not a multiplexer - though it has multiple inputs and one output - that's why it's labeled and the others aren't.

Comment: If its a multiplexer I wonder what the selector signals would be. But I could very well see that the symbol is inspired by the selector symbols

Comment: @wirrbel The ALU's selector signals would be used to tell it which operation to perform (addition, shift, or, and, not, multiply, etc.).